# Deadlock when running 2 transactional method with Spring Data and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, transactions, spring-data

I am try to understand transactions using Spring Boot, Spring Data and MySQL.

I created service `UpdateService` which is used to update record in database. Methods `change` and `change2` executes transactionally.

```
@Autowired
private UserRepo userRepo;

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void change() {
    User user = userRepo.findOne("Jan");

    write("before change", user);
    sleep(2000);
    user.setPassword("new password");
    write("after change", user);
}

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void change2() {
    User user = userRepo.findOne("Jan");

    write("before change2", user);
    user.setSecondName("new name");
    write("after change2", user);
}
```

and when I call `change` and `change2` methods I received these logs:

```
before change User(name=Jan, secondName=Adam, password=Kowalski)
before change2 User(name=Jan, secondName=Adam, password=Kowalski)
after change2 User(name=Jan, secondName=new name, password=Kowalski)
after change User(name=Jan, secondName=Adam, password=new password)
```

...and after that also I got this exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

My question is this: Why does the transaction for `change2` start before `change` is done? What is the reason of deadlock?

Comment: Could you please give more context? ie. How `change` and `change2` are executed? Are they executed concurrently?

Comment: they are executed form controller
    @RequestMapping("/change")
    private void change() {
        updateService.change();
    }
change2 looks similar

They are executed concurently: I exec in postman change and immediately change2 (that is the reason i added sleep for to 2s to prevent finish first transaction before second wants to start)

Comment: In your code nothing prevents `change2` to only start after `change` finish its transaction. The `findOne` method executes a select in `SHARE MODE` which allow concurrent read. What I do not understand is the deadlock.

Comment: I think your question was answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747906/getting-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarting-transaction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bellow is my viewpoint:

> why transaction change2 starts before change is done?

For mysql, first you need to care about **the version of MySQL**，and see [this official site url about transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html). Specially, the description of Isolation Level **SERIALIZABLE**:

- This level is like REPEATABLE READ, **but InnoDB implicitly converts all plain SELECT statements to SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE if autocommitis disabled. If autocommit is enabled**(That says, the **read operation** of **change** won't block the **read operation** of **change2**), the SELECT is its own transaction. It therefore is known to be read only and can be serialized if performed as a consistent (nonlocking) read and need not block for other transactions. (To force a plain SELECT to block if other transactions have modified the selected rows, disable autocommit.

> What is the reason of deadlock?

When read operation of **change** and **change2** is executing, that says two transactions have hold the **Shared Lock** on the same row. When executing write operation of **change**(transaction t1) and **change2**(transaction t2), t1 will wait on t2 releases the **Shared Lock** and t2 also will wait on t1 releases the **Shared Lock**, so this will lead to dead lock.

I suggest you see the **Transaction and Lock Mechanism** of MySQL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-model.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-lock-modes.html

Hope to help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was looking for solution in JPA. I didn't expect that was mysql configuration.